# python exit with segmentation error using PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Trying to open 2 windows using PyQt5 we experienced a brutal python exit with segmentation error message.

The minimal reproducing error is:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
>>> def application():
...     import sys
...     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
...     Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
...     Dialog.show()
...     app.exec_()
... 
>>> import sys
>>> app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
>>> MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
>>> list = application()
>>> MainWindow.show()
Segmentation error (core dumped)
```

We suspect that the first window hamper the second window opening.
How can we open the two windows without problem ?

Comment: Why are you creating two `QApplication` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it's because I've created 2 QApplication objects that I have a problem.
Also this program works with this code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

def application():
    import sys
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    Dialog.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    list = application()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```